# View all commands and their outputs in command prompt in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I have a requirement and I am wondering if it is possible. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

I need to view the entire history in the command prompt window that I am using. Currently, when I scroll up in the command prompt window, I can see the commands that I have run and their outputs. Now, obviously, some of the previous commands and their outputs will not be visible even if I scroll up as they are out of view in the command prompt window. My question is, how can I see the entire history of commands and outputs for a given session  (including previous commands that were run in the current session and their outputs?)

Thanks,

Mithun

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of the command to a text file. [This](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/redirect-command-output-to-file.htm) article explains how to do that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Spencer4134. Thanks for your suggestion. However, it is only useful for commands that I'll run in the future. What I am looking for is to retrieve all commands that were previously run and their outputs (including the commands that are no longer visible in the command prompt window).

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like there is no way to do that. You can try F7 and see if that works, but I don't think that shows output. Someone asked a question similar to yours: http://serverfault.com/questions/95404/is-there-a-global-persistent-cmd-history

Comment: I second your opinion, looks like there is no way. F7 also does not do anything useful apart from opening a dialog box that does nothing. Thanks for your time and help!